# How did this website do their splash page/age verification?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, web

I am looking at this website - http://www.shopmss.com/ - and I was wondering how they did the splash page, age verification and store all on the same URL 'shopmss.com'. You click through 3 screens before you get back to the store.

My secondary question is, can you do this without setting a cookie? i.e. Javascript, that appends the browser bar URL? Or something with `mod_rewrite`?

EDIT: I thought this was a relevant question to ask because I was exploring the best practice to accomplish the task, I figured it would have something technical. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site is setting a cookie called `BX`. That could be tracking a session, in which they can display different content based on the state of the session.

Comment: So, based on the state of this `BX` cookie, it will serve 3 different files?

Comment: I'm saying it's hard to tell what's going on on the server side. There is no way of us knowing for sure. But if it's planting cookies, it's possible for any of those pages to show different content depending on whether or not the user has performed any kind of action.

Answer (score -2):

They are using a frameset. Check the source.

Comment: But when you return to the site later, it remembers that you've accepted the terms of service. There is more going on there.

Comment: It doesn't for me. I have tried in both Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome now. It does set a cookie for shopmss.com though as well three cookies for shopmss2.businesscatalyst.com